# Check in shellscript if a variable is partially the same as a parameter

Tags: bash, shell

So this is admittedly for university, but I can't find the answer anywhere, nor online, nor in the lecture notes.

I basically take a parameter, and have to search, if that is part of a longer string I have already stored:

```
if [ *$param* = $var ]
then
...
```

is the part in question. Now what is really weird for me, is that no matter if it says = or !=, the code nested under then never gets executed. I checked every other part of the code very thoroughly, and it all looks to be working fine.

Do you have any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Also, here a link to the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf) which I've resorted many times in the past (and still do).

Comment: @sal, please **don't** advise the ABS to others -- it's notorious as a source of bad-practice examples and outdated information (and has been for years -- see the timestamps next to the irc.freenode.org #bash factoid database entry in http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs; they're in epoch time, so #bash advice has been to skip the ABS since ~2008). The [bash-hackers' wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/) and the [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) are much better-maintained alternatives; there's also a lot of content overlap in the [BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the additional pointers, I will check those out myself!

Answer (score 3):

You just need to reverse the arguments. Inside `[[ ... ]]`, `=`, `==`, and `!=` can perform pattern matching if the right-hand operand contains unescaped meta characters like `*` and `?`, or a bracket expression `[...]`.

```
if [[ $var == *"$param"* ]];   # check if $param is a substring of $var
```

Your code may or may not have performed pattern matching (depending on the contents of `$var`, but you were seeing if the string with the value of `$param` embedded in literal `*`s matched the value of `$var`.

For example, `[[ foobar == *oba* ]]` would succeed, as `oba` is a substring of `foobar`.  `[[ *oba* == foobar ]]` would not, since `*oba*` and `foobar` are two distinct different strings. `[[ *oba* == *oba ]]` would also fail, since `*oba*` is not a string that ends with `oba`.

Comment: Note that for strict matching, you should put the variable on the right in double-quotes (but not the wildcards!), like this: `[[ $var == *"$param"* ]]`. This forces any wildcard-type characters in the string to be matched literally.

Answer (score 0):

I would use grep

```
if echo $var | grep -q $param; then
  echo "found it!"
fi
```

Comment: Quite buggy -- try this if your `param` contains spaces, or if your `var` contains the two-character string `-n`. (Also, spinning up a pipeline means you're `fork()`ing at least twice, and then using an `execve()` to replace off one of the forked-off subshells with an instance of `grep` for something the shell itself could do built-in).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if [[ $var =~ $param ]]; then
    echo "matches"
fi
```

Comment: This is a regex, not a glob -- a very different syntax.

Comment: ...for example, if `param='.txt'`, `[[ $var =~ $param ]]` will match `atxt` even though `a` is not `.` (since `.` is a single-character wildcard in POSIX ERE regex syntax); whereas `[[ $var = *"$param"* ]]` will only match the precise substring.